# How to set a timer to automatically update database table at a fixed time of everyday

Tags: c#

What is the best way to implement a timer to automatically update database table? A code sample would be great! I want the target method invoked every 24hours, it would be acceptable for the method to fire at 18:30 on a daily basis.

I am working with  c#

Comment: scheduled task?

Comment: Use a stored procedure, trigger and/or background process. Depends on the framework and source.

Comment: If possible, transform your data representation so that it's not necessary. E.g. store fixed data and leave any computations based on that data to occur on demand - for instance, rather than storing someone's age, you'd store the DOB and compute their age.

Comment: Assuming you're using sql server, you should be able to schedule a job on the database. If you need to use c#, you can schedule a job through windows or check out  the hangfire library

Comment: have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: How would you gather data to update? Do your SQL knows that data? If yes you can use SQL jobs to schedule this update.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, would definitely try it each way to see which works best

Comment: Mark the one you chose as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in lots of different ways but using third party libraries is mostly the safest method. So i recommend you [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

You can handle your background operations and schedule them. For your example you can use recurring jobs.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
    Cron.Daily);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple class to do this.

```
class DailyTaskRunner
    {
        private DateTime _lastDateRun = DateTime.MinValue;

        Timer _timer;

        public DailyTaskRunner(TimeSpan timeOfDay, Action task)
        {
            _timer = new Timer((o) =>
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= timeOfDay && DateTime.Today != _lastDateRun)
                {
                    _lastDateRun = DateTime.Today;
                    task();
                }

            }, null, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    void TestTask()
            {
                DailyTaskRunner r = new DailyTaskRunner(TimeSpan.FromHours(8) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43), () => Console.WriteLine("I'm a daily task, run at " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
while(true)
{
if(DateTime.Now.Hour==18 && DateTime.Now.Minute==30)
```

{
    call your update function here.

}

}
This piece of code will run forever.When the time condition is met it will update the database.

Comment: This is invalid code, `datetime` isn't the correct name for the struct, `now` also isn't capitalized to match the static field. `18:30` isn't a string, or any other kind of variable type.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.